# Customizing the entry uniqueness in Django

Tags: django, parameter-passing, unique-index

I have a database containing a list of ingredients. I'd like to avoid duplicate entries in this table. I don't want to use the `unique` keyword for 2 reasons :

- My uniqueness constraints are a bit more sophisticated than a mere `=`
- I don't want to raise an exception when a pre-existing ingredient model is created, instead I just want to return that model, so that I can write `Ingredient(ingredient_name='tomato')` and just go on with my day rather than encapsulating all of that in a `try` clause. This will allow me to easily add ingredients to my recipe table on the fly.

One solution is simply to have a wrapper function like `create_ingredient`, but I don't find that to be particularly elegant and more specifically it's not robust to some other developer down the line simply forgetting to use the wrapper. So instead, I'm playing around with the pre_init and post_init signals.

Here's what I have so far :

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    ingredient_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    recipes = models.ManyToManyField(Recipe,related_name='ingredients')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ingredient_name

class Name(models.Model):
    main_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=None)
    equivalent_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True, default=None)

def _add_ingredient(sender, args, **kwargs):
    if 'ingredient_name' not in kwargs['kwargs'] :
        return
    kwargs['kwargs']['ingredient_name'] = kwargs['kwargs']['ingredient_name'].lower()
    # check if equivalent name exists, make this one the main one otherwise
    try:
        kwargs['kwargs']['ingredient_name'] = Name.objects.filter(
            equivalent_name=kwargs['kwargs']['ingredient_name']
        )[0].main_name
    except IndexError:
        name = Name(main_name=kwargs['kwargs']['ingredient_name'],
                equivalent_name=kwargs['kwargs']['ingredient_name'])
        name.save()

pre_init.connect(_add_ingredient, Ingredient)
```

So far so good. This actually works and will replace `ingredient_name` when needed before the model is initialized. Now what I'd like is to check if the ingredient in question already exists and have the initializer return it if it does. I think I need to play around with `post_init` to do this but I don't know how to modify the particular instance that's being created. Here's what I mean by that :

```
def _finalize_ingredient(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    try:
        # doesn't work because of python's "pass arguments in python's super unique way of doing things" thing
        instance = Ingredient.objects.filter(ingredient_name=instance.ingredient_name)[0]
    except IndexError:
        pass

post_init.connect(_finalize_ingredient, Ingredient)
```

As I've commented, I don't expect this to work because `instance = ...` doesn't actually modify `instance`, it just reassigns the variable name (incidentally if you try to run this all sorts of terrible things happen which I don't care to understand because I know this is flat out wrong). So how do I actually do this ? I really hope wrapper functions aren't the cleanest option here. I'm a big fan of OOP and gosh darn it I want an OOP solution to this (which, as I've said, I think in the long run would be much more robust and safer than wrappers).

I realize of course that I can add an `add_ingredient` method to Recipe which will do all of this for me, but I really like the idea of containing all of this in my `Ingredient` class as it will guarantee the proper database behavior under any circumstance. I'm also curious as to know if/how the `post_init` method can be used to completely override the created object for a given circumstance.

By the way, some of you may be wondering why I don't have a `ForeignKey` entry in my `Name` class that would connect the `Name` table to the `Ingredient` table. After all, isn't this what my check is essentially accomplishing in my `_add_ingredient` method ? One of the reasons is that if I do this then I end up with the same problem I'm trying to solve here : If I want to create an ingredient on the fly to add it to my recipe, I could simply create a `Name` object when creating an `Ingredient` object, but that would raise an exception if it corresponds to a `main_name` that is already in use (rather than simply returning the object I need).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [`get_or_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create), which is already a built-in in Django.

You mention:

> One solution is simply to have a wrapper function like `create_ingredient`, but I don't find that to be particularly elegant and more specifically it's not robust to some other developer down the line simply forgetting to use the wrapper.

Well, look at it the other way around. What if you actually need to create a "duplicate" ingredient? Then it is nice to have the possibility.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with something that is as elegant and robust as I think it's possible to be given what I'm after. I've still had to define an `add_ingredient` method, but I still have the robustness that I need. I've made it so that it can be generalized to any class with a primary key, and the `Name` table will contain the info that will define the name uniqueness of any table :

```
class Name(models.Model):
    main_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=None)
    equivalent_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True, default=None)

def _pre_init_unique_fetcher(sender, args, **kwargs):
    pk_name = sender._meta.pk.name
    if pk_name not in kwargs['kwargs'] :
        return
    kwargs['kwargs'][pk_name] = kwargs['kwargs'][pk_name].lower()
    # check if equivalent name exists, make this one the main one otherwise
    try:
        kwargs['kwargs'][pk_name] = Name.objects.filter(
            equivalent_name=kwargs['kwargs'][pk_name]
        )[0].main_name
    except IndexError:
        name = Name(main_name=kwargs['kwargs'][pk_name],
                    equivalent_name=kwargs['kwargs'][pk_name])
        name.save()
    sender._input_dict = kwargs['kwargs']

def _post_init_unique_fetcher(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    pk_name = sender._meta.pk.name
    pk_instance = instance.__dict__[pk_name]
    filter_dict = {}
    filter_dict[pk_name] = pk_instance
    try:
        post_init.disconnect(_post_init_unique_fetcher,sender)
        instance.__dict__ = sender.objects.filter(**filter_dict)[0].__dict__
        post_init.connect(_post_init_unique_fetcher, sender)
        for key in sender._input_dict:
            instance.__dict__[key] = sender._input_dict[key]
    del sender._input_dict
    except IndexError:
        post_init.connect(_post_init_unique_fetcher, sender)
    except:
        post_init.connect(_post_init_unique_fetcher, sender)
        raise

unique_fetch_models = [Ingredient, Recipe, WeekPlan]
for unique_fetch_model in unique_fetch_models :
    pre_init.connect(_pre_init_unique_fetcher, unique_fetch_model)
    post_init.connect(_post_init_unique_fetcher, unique_fetch_model)
```

Now what this will do is load up any new model with the pre-existing data of the previous model (rather than the default values) if one with the same name exists. The reason I still need an `add_ingredient` method in my `Recipe` class is because I can't call `Ingredient.objects.create()` for a pre-existing ingredient without raising an exception despite the fact that I can create the model and immediately save it. This has to do with how Django handles the `primary_key` designation : if you create the model then `save` it, it assumes you're just updating the entry if it already exists with that key, and yet if you `create` it, it tries to add another entry and that conflicts with the `primary_key` designation. So now I can do things like `recipe.add_ingredient(Ingredient(ingredient_name='tomato', vegetarian=True))`.